# XML object storage

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I've created an XML pull-parser which pulls details of an xml out:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(response3.getEntity().getContent()));
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
        System.out.println("Start document");
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
    }
    eventType = xpp.next();
}
```

This searches through the XML correctly pulling out different tags etc.

My problem is now that I wish to store these. The basic structure is that it stores a series of cards, each with an attribute list. The outer tag would be something like `<card>` and inside there would be many attributes such as `<resourceid>`, `<price>` etc.

I wish to store each card in an easy to retrieve manner. I was thinking of using SQlite but have very little experience with it.Is it possible to do this as the parser steps through?

---

Added my class here

```
public class SecondActivity {

        String resourceid;
        String startprice;
        String currentbid;
        String buynowprice;
        String expires;

        public String getResourceId(){
            return this.resourceid;
        }

        public String getStartPrice(){
            return this.startprice;
        }

        public String getCurrentBid(){
            return this.currentbid;
        }

        public String getBuyNowPrice(){
            return this.buynowprice;
        }

        public String getExpires(){
            return this.expires;
        }

        public void setResourceId(String resourceidin){
            this.resourceid = resourceidin;
        }

        public void setStartPrice(String startpricein){
            this.startprice = startpricein;
        }

        public void setCurrentBid(String currentbidin){
            this.currentbid = currentbidin;
        }

        public void setBuyNowPrice(String buynowpricein){
            this.buynowprice = buynowpricein;
        }

        public void setExpires(String expiresin){
            this.expires = expiresin;
        }
    }
```

I now just call each statement i.e. the set inside where the parser finds the tag values, I then call a store, passing it this object? How do I then clear all values inside object?
Thanks for all the help, most appreciated.

Trying to find the start of the card as defined by

added this to my code:

```
else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                 if (xpp.getName() == "auctionInfo"){
                     this.setMyflag(1);
                     System.out.println("IN THE IF FLAG IS SET TO 1");
                 }

                 System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
```

Unfortunately it never enters the if, and I am stumped as to why!

Comment: For Androids memory purposes, I wouldn't use all the getter and setter-methods but make the fields public. To clear all the fields, you can add a `clearAll`-method that just sets all fields to `null`. After you have your full Object, you pass it to the database-method which then gets the values from your Object and inserts them in the Database. Please be more clear about what your problem is now.

Comment: My problem now, is that I am an android noob - and am attempting my first application. This is great, you really have been fantastic, so rather than adding the setters etc just change the declerations to public String expires; etc?

I am normally a python man myself, this android stuff is a steep learning curve!

Comment: Yep, simply make your fields public.

Comment: You are a hero, thanks very much, I may be back later, but am going to go and attempt this now.

Comment: Updating original post, could you take a quick look again please, thanks man!

Comment: Please post longer comments or code-passages as an edit in your original post. Also, `System.out.println()` doesn't work on Android, use [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) to debug. Last but not least, what's the problem?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I realised and editted it. System.out.println() has been working in all the other lines. I'll change it to a log command now and see if it changes anything.

Comment: No difference with the Log.w("IN IF", "IM IN HERE"); in it's place, I have printed the xpp.getName() and it is deffinately auctionInfo, completely stumped here.

Comment: Looks like a typical newby-mistake to me. I updated my post, check if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you once again, sorry for the schoolboy error. You really are a hero!

Comment: I am struggling to edit the values of these variables stored in the other class, how should I be doing it? Keep getting nullpointer exception. Thanks

Comment: Edit your original post, add the StackTrace and the bit of your code that is necessary to understand them.

Comment: Actually I found my error, it was of course a rookie mistake - referring to a variable before it had been given a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. For some input about how to use SQLite in Android, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

You could (for example) create a class which holds the informations for one of your `<card>`-tags (to build something like a data-package for one card) and then perform the Database-Inserts in another method which takes an Object of this class and processes it.

---

Your `<card>`-element will have multiple child-elements or attributes. Those are the fields you for your new class. When the parser finds one of those Child-Elements/Attributes, you set the corresponding field in your class.

When the parser finds the next `<card>`-element, you first call your `storeCardInDB()`-method (or whatever you call it) and pass it the filled out Object.

The method will take the fields from your Object, bind them to a PreparedStatement (for example) and send it to the Database.

This is done for every `<card>`-element in your XML-File.

---

Okay, there is a difference in comparing two `int`s and two `String`s. If you want to know if the content of a String matches the content of another String, you'll need to use the `equals()`-method:

```
if ( xpp.getName().equals("auctionInfo") ) {[...]}
```

Here is [a nice article](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml) which should clear the background of this behavior.

Comment: This sounds like a greate idea, how would I go about storing the <card> tag in a class?

Comment: I have updated the original post, could you take a quick look please? thanks for all the help!